# Calculate $I= \int_{\ 0}^{\pi }\frac{\sin(x)\ln(x)}{\ln(\pi x-x^2)}dx$

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

What I thought:
For this type of integral to work, one needs to solve it by symmetry. The only one which seem to work in this case is:
$$I=\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x \ln x}{\ln(\pi x-x^2)}dx$$I don't know if this can work that$$\int_0^a f(x)dx=\frac12 \int_0^a (f(x) +f(a-x))dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy is just right (with $a=\pi,\,f(x)=\frac{\sin x\ln x}{\ln x+\ln(\pi-x)}$): it gives $I=\frac12\int_0^\pi\sin xdx=1$.